# Why are stateful widgets defined as two classes in flutter?

Tags: generics, dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter/dart, so while I try to make an app I also try to understand why things are a certain way. In the flutter docs there is example code of a stateful widget as shown:

```
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => new _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Why are they defined with two classes as opposed to one? I'm guessing the State class can be used somewhere else so it was better to be split up.
2. From what I understand the `createState()` function returns an object of type `State`, so having `_YellowBirdState extends State` makes sense, but why is `YellowBird` passed into the generic class of `State`? My guess it has something to do with `Yellowbird` extending the `StatefulWidget` class but not quite sure.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are multiple reasons :

- Widgets are immutable. Since `StatefulWidget` extends `Widget` it therefore must be immutable too. Splitting the declaration into two classes allows both `StatefulWidget` to be immutable and  `State` to be mutable.
- Widgets are instantiated using the syntax `new MyWidget()`. If we merged both classes into one, `new MyWidget()` would reset all the properties of the state every time its parent update.

As for the explanation of `class _MyStatefulState extends State<MyStateful>`

That is because the `State` class can access to it's `Stateful` part using the `this.widget` field.
The generic is here to make that field of type `MyStateful` instead of just `StatefulWidget`. As you may want to access `MyStateful` properties.

Comment: This explanation with immutability doesn't really work for me. It is sort of saying, I am a teetotaller, but I'm drinking for my twin. If the widget needs state (the clue is in the name), it is merely pretending to be immutable. 

Also, I'm not convinced about the use case of multiple widgets needing access to the same state.Surely that's not the common case to be optimized for.

Answer (score 29):

1. One of the main design decisions of Flutter is that it is cheap to re-create Widgets, so `build()` can be called to rebuild a branch of the widget tree when something changes. This works fine for stateless widgets which are given their immutable values through the constructor. But stateful widgets need to preserve their state across builds. In your example, the framework can create multiple `YellowBird`s, but it only ever creates one `YellowBirdState`. Each newly created `YellowBird` gets transparently hooked up to the existing `YellowBirdState` by the framework.
2. A subclass of `State` needs to know its Widget type so that the compiler knows what type the variable `widget` is. In `YellowBirdState` you can refer to the Widget with `widget`. If `YellowBird` had a member variable `final String foo`, the compiler knows that `widget.foo` is the String called foo in `YellowBird`.

Comment: `But stateful widgets need to preserve their state across builds. In your example, the framework can create multiple YellowBirds, but it only ever creates one YellowBirdState` 

Will there always be one state or one state per instance of the Widget? If we had only one state, would that not mean displaying the same value in every Widget?

Comment: Every stateful widget creates its own stateful element and each stateful element creates a state object by calling the createState method.(Adding it here for anyone referring it in the future)

Answer (score 7):

The [Flutter documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview#widget-state) explains this.

> Having separate state and widget objects lets other widgets treat both stateless and stateful widgets in exactly the same way, without being concerned about losing state. Instead of needing to hold on to a child to preserve its state, the parent can create a new instance of the child at any time without losing the child’s persistent state. The framework does all the work of finding and reusing existing state objects when appropriate.

Basically, its so that a Stateful Widget can be re-instantiated (whenever its `build()`, e.g. from a state change) without losing its state.

This is also enforced by Widgets being immutable, so the mutable state data must be stored elsewhere: the `State` object.

Answer (score 4):

```dart
class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget
```

StatefulWidget is an immutable class (Immutable class means that once an object is created, we cannot change its values).

1. The class must be declared as final (So that child classes can’t be created).
2. Data members in the class must be declared as final. (So that we can’t change the value of it after object creation).
3. A parameterized constructor.
4. Getter method for all the variables in it. No setters (To not have the option to change
   the value of the instance variable).

---

```dart
class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird>
```

State class which type is generic is a mutable class that can be instantiated with different values after creating its object.

Same as this StatefulWidget class which is immutable is calling a function of `createState()` which define the class `State` of the widget after its called in a flutter
so we can change the values of the widget again and again by this approach but we cannot change the type of Stateful or Stateless.

Comment: Please try to use the code snippets if you want to give a code example or explanation. 

Try to build your comments via using shorter nicer explanations.