# What is the 'state' of widgets outside of a class

Tags: dart, flutter

I've started some work with flutter and I'm curious about the 'state' of a widget outside of a class. When I move `searchAndAddRow` outside of the build function inside of the `myApp` class I need to declare the Widget as final, makes sense because it's a stateless class. When I move the Widget completely outside of a class (like I have done in the code snippet) I don't need to define anything.

In both cases when I move `searchAndAddRow` outside of `MyApp`'s `build` the "hot reload" functionality in android studio doesn't work, the app requires stopping and restarting for the changes to take effect. Which kinda prompted me to ask this question in the first place.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

Widget searchAndAddRow = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Icon(const IconData(0xe8b6, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
      new Container(
        width: 80.0,
        child: TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              border: const UnderlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'search'),
        ),
      ),
      new Expanded(
        child: new Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(const IconData(0xe148, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
            tooltip: 'Add a new item!',
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ]),
      )
    ],
  ),
);

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App Title', // App title
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('App Bar Title (Home)'),
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: [
              //Row 1 contains: Search and Add
              searchAndAddRow
              //Row 2 contains: List
              //Row 3 contains: Sort dropdown
            ],
          )
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, you didn't define a widget. You defined a variable.

Variables are not hot-reloaded because it is not possible for the framework to know if you want to use the old or new value.

In general, **do not extract a widget tree into variables**. Instead extract them into another widget:

```
/** DON"T */
Widget foo = Container();

/** DO */

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

---

**But what if it is constant? For optimization purposes**

Well, you can define a `const` constructor to your widgets :

```
class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  const Foo();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

This means that whenever you do `const Foo()` (the `const` keyword is not required since dart 2.0), it will always return the exact same widget instance.

Basically, it does the same as if you'd extract it into a constant variable. But implicitly, therefore hot-reload still works.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to understand the principle of why widgets should be extracted into another widget, and why here is separate State for every stateful widget:
[Why are stateful widgets defined as two classes in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612237/why-are-stateful-widgets-defined-as-two-classes-in-flutter)

The main idea is to hold widget-objects in a static tree defining their UI properties (eg, TextStyle, color, child) inside constructor. Like HTML DOM, where the stateful is a div-container in which you can place some State