# why do we require State method inside a Statefulwidget in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Why we need 'State' class if we can put all code to '

Actually a stateless widget is unable to implement changes in internal data. So for that purpose we use the stateful widget.
But why we use a stateless widget inside a stateful widget?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main()
{
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget
{
  State<StatefulWidget>createState()
  {
    return _MyAppStore();
  }
}

class _MyAppStore extends State<MyApp>
{
  List<String> _products= ['food tester'];       
  build(context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar:AppBar(
          title:Text("abe title hai yaar!!")
        ),
        body: Column(
          children:[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.00),
            child:RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child:Text('VETO')
            ),
            ),
           Column(
             children: _products.map((element)=> Card(
               child:Column(
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Image.asset('assets/samantha.jpg'),
                   Text(element)
                 ],
               ),
               ))
               .toList(),
           ),
          ],
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

tatefulwidget'?

Comment: What stateless widget or state method sre you talking about?

Comment: class _MyAppStore extends State<MyApp>   im talking about this state

Comment: I hope the flutter/dart Devs will simplify the creation of stateful widgets too

Comment: It's just that stateful widgets consist of 2 parts, the widget and the state. The same widget can be reused multiple times with different state instances https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Comment: simplify the creatiin - very unlikely, but you'll get used to it and IDEs provide shortcuts to create them anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are stateful widgets defined as two classes in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612237/why-are-stateful-widgets-defined-as-two-classes-in-flutter)

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to understand your question. Please make clear what you are asking.

Comment: thanks @GünterZöchbauer i have got the answer.